# TcpListener send heartbeat every 5 seconds and read message from client async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, tcplistener

I'm writing a TcpListener service that runs as a Windows Service that a vendor software client will connect to. I can't change the client's implementation and must adhere to their spec.

I have the part that receives messages and returns a response working. The problem I have is the clients expect a heartbeat message (`S0000E`) to be sent every 5 seconds, to which it replies with the same message. I'm not sure how to add that functionality in among the async/await stuff I'm doing to handle the real messages received from the clients.

OnStart

```
_serverListenerTask = Task.Run(() => AcceptClientsAsync(_listener, _cancellationToken.Token));
```

AcceptClientsAsync

```
static async Task AcceptClientsAsync(TcpListener listener, CancellationToken ct)
{
    var clientCounter = 0;
    while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync()
                                         .ConfigureAwait(false);
        clientCounter++;
        await ReceiveMessageAsync(client, clientCounter, ct);
    }
}
```

ReceiveMessageAsync

```
static async Task ReceiveMessageAsync(TcpClient client, int clientIndex, CancellationToken ct)
{
    Log.Info("New client ({0}) connected", clientIndex);
    using (client)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[4096];
        var stream = client.GetStream();
        while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
            var amountReadTask = stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, ct);

            var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(timeoutTask, amountReadTask)
                                          .ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (completedTask == timeoutTask)
            {
                var msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Client timed out");
                await stream.WriteAsync(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                break;
            }

            var bytesRead = amountReadTask.Result;
            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                // Nothing was read
                break;
            }

            // Snip... Handle message from buffer here

            await stream.WriteAsync(responseBuffer, 0, responseBuffer.Length, ct)
                        .ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
    Log.Info("Client ({0}) disconnected", clientIndex);
}
```

I thought I could add a heartbeat task to the `Task.WhenAny`, but that caused the heartbeat to always fire and I could never read the response. I also tried sending the heartbeat before the timeout and read tasks, which worked for sending, but then I was either reading the heartbeat response and not the next message in line or the timeout task would complete and disconnect the client. Essentially, if the heartbeat exchange is successful then the client shouldn't be disconnected after that 15 second delay.

Comment: How do you separate one message from another message?

Comment: Am I reading this right that normally the protocol is client request -> server response but in this particular instance its server heartbeat -> client heartbeat? Are there particular rules in the protocol such that e.g. it is/isn't allowed for you to send a heartbeat message while a response is outstanding? A clear definition of the (types of) messages involved here and the rules surrounding them (i.e. "the protocol") would help.

Comment: It seems inherently racy as well if the server chooses to send the heartbeat at the exact same moment that the client chooses to send a request.

Comment: You should be able to get away with dropping the timeout requirement. If you send periodic heartbeats, you'll detect broken connections.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, normally the client is sending messages which the server must acknowledge with a confirmation message as the response. However, the heartbeat is expected to be sent from the server and returned from the client. I don't know if there are rules around when it can/can't be sent. Unfortunately there's no documentation on this legacy vendor protocol.

Comment: All of the messages are expected to begin with the header `S0000E`, where the zeros are the padded number of bytes in the message after the header. For example, the message "Hello" would be sent as "S0005EHello".

Answer (score 2):

Implementing TCP server-client is not a simple task. However, the following way of implementation, if you improve it to be more efficient in resources, can be a practical solution:

Server:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Server
{
    public class Program
    {
        static List<SocketBuffer> clients = new List<SocketBuffer>();
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Receive from any IP, listen on port 65000 in this machine
            var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 65000);
            var t = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    listener.Start();
                    var task = listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                    task.Wait();
                    clients.Add(new SocketBuffer(task.Result, new byte[4096]));
                }
            });
            t.Wait();    //It will remain here, do in a better way if you like !
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// We need this class because each TcpClient will have its own buffer
    /// </summary>
    class SocketBuffer
    {
        public SocketBuffer(TcpClient client, byte[] buffer)
        {
            this.client = client;
            stream = client.GetStream();
            this.buffer = buffer;

            receiveData(null);
        }

        private TcpClient client;
        private NetworkStream stream;
        private byte[] buffer;

        private object _lock = new object();
        private async void receiveData(Task<int> result)
        {
            if (result != null)
            {
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    int numberOfBytesRead = result.Result;
                    //If no data read, it means we are here to be notified that the tcp client has been disconnected
                    if (numberOfBytesRead == 0)
                    {
                        onDisconnected();
                        return;
                    }
                    //We need a part of this array, you can do it in more efficient way if you like
                    var segmentedArr = new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead).ToArray();
                    OnDataReceived(segmentedArr);
                }

            }
            var task = stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            //This is not recursion in any sense because the current 
            //thread will be free and the call to receiveData will be from a new thread
            await task.ContinueWith(receiveData);       
        }

        private void onDisconnected()
        {
            //Add your code here if you want this event
        }

        private void OnDataReceived(byte[] dat)
        {
            //Do anything with the data, you can reply here. I will just pring the received data from the demo client
            string receivedTxt = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dat);
            Console.WriteLine(receivedTxt);
        }
    }
}
```

Demo client:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace Client
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            var task = client.ConnectAsync("localhost", 65000);
            task.Wait();
            if(client.Connected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Client connected");
                var stream = client.GetStream();
                var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test");
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Client NOT connected");
            }
            Thread.Sleep(60000);
        }
    }
}
```